# laravel authentication from existing table and project

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-authorization

I have a existing project in php. I am moving project from core to laravel. but I am getting problem to implement the admin authentication from existing table. As I did much research on that and I found that there are some commands to create authentication functionality automatically.

Please some one help me to create authentication process manually using laravel model and from exist table table.

Comment: check this url: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23431415/can-the-laravel-auth-system-use-an-existing-database

Comment: Thanks for sending me the URL. Can you suggest how can I make user model which fits the controller code with example.

Comment: is the admin and user on same table?, need bit more info, are you using jwt auth?

Comment: admin auth table is different from user table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this steps:

1. Modify your existing table for Laravel authentication by changing or adding this columns:

   - `username` (string)
   - `password` (string)
   - `created_at` (datetime)
   - `updated_at` (datetime)
   - `remember_token` (string)
2. Change existing passwords to [Bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) hash type that is the default hashing method in Laravel or read some guide like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710897/how-to-use-sha1-encryption-instead-of-bcrypt-in-laravel-4) to force Laravel work in your existing hashing function.
3. Make Laravel `User` model. You can do it like [any tutorial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) with Laravel Migration. It must be like this:

   ```
   <?php namespace App;

   use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
   use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
   use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
   use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

   class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {

       use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

       protected $table = 'users';

       protected $fillable = ['password', 'username', 'email'];

       protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];
   }
   ```
4. Read [Laravel Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) class guide. It's easy, for example you can check if user is login or not with `Auth::check()` function, or try to login like this :

   ```
   if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
       // Authentication passed...
   }
   ```